# Stop the code execution after window.location.reload() and prevent .always ajax event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to stop the code execution after window.location.reload() and prevent .always ajax event?

Here is a basic (simplified) code that can be run even from the browser console.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    window.location.reload();
    alert( "don't show this because of page reload" );

  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "and don't show that because of page reload in the fail" );
  });
```

Can we change the code within .fail event somehow so that .always never occurs?

I need to find a solution without removing .always. Once we reload the page within fail based on if-else statements, we don't want .always ever happened.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Using alert() is a horrible debugging tool. What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl, the problem is .always block gets executed after window.location.reload(); within .fail. And that is a problem.

Comment: You can do everything inside of `.always`, you can check inside for fail or success of your request and act accordingly, a good discussion on this was posted some time ago: [ajax-always-or-ajax-complete](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-always-or-ajax-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a flag:

```
var dontshow = false;
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    dontshow = true;
    window.location.reload();
    return;
    alert( "don't show this because of page reload" );

  })
  .always(function() {
    if(dontshow) return;
    alert( "and don't show that because of page reload in the fail" );
  });
```